# Why doesn't Page Title pull [node:title] in to all pages

Tags: meta-tags, nodes

In the Metatags section of each page, the [node:title] field is supposed to pull the data into the Page Title. This works for many articles on our site, but doesn't for and many seemingly random others that are formatted exactly the same.

There really doesn’t seem to be any rhyme or reason.